# Apollo server accessing all datasources within resolvers before API request is sent

Tags: graphql, datasource, apollo, apollo-server, graphql-js

In a graphql query with multiple resolvers, I'm looking for a way to count how many times datasources are called before the first datasource API request is sent. The project that I am working on requires me to either allow or stop all the requests if the number of the datasources called within resolvers in a graphql query exceeds a certain number. 
I am using an instance of the `RESTDataSource` to make API calls and each one of the resolvers call one or more datasources from the `RESTDataSource` class. I've been looking into this and far as I know, the `RESTDataSource` class doesn't have a method that shows me all the datasources requested because it is only called by the resolver and per request.

My problem is, I'm not finding a place where I can have access to all the datasources that will be called before the request is sent. I found that in the Apollo server instantiation, the only thing that I have access to are the resolvers, and not the datasources within each resolver, and as far as I know, not before the request is made so I can't stop it if the number of datasources calls exceed a certain threshold. I was hoping I could access that in the `willSendRequest` method inside the `RESTDataSource` class since from what I know, this is the only method that intercepts the request before being sent, but I don't think it's possible.

I'm pretty new to Apollo and I've been reading about this but didn't find a solution. I'd really appreciate any help.

Here's a simplified snippet of my code (not the original code):

`resolvers.ts`

```
export const resolvers: Resolvers = {
  Query: {
    getCompanies: (_, __, { dataSources }) => {
      return dataSources.companyDatasource.getCompanies();
    },
    getCompany: (_, { name }, { dataSources }) => {
      return dataSources.companyDatasource.getCompanyByName(name);
    },
    getCompanyCEOs: async (_, { name }, { dataSources }) => {
      const company = await dataSources.companyDatasource.getCompanyByName(name);
      return dataSources.companyDatasource.getCEOs(company.id);
    },
....
```

`company.datasource.ts`

```
export default class CompanyDatasource extends RESTDataSource {
  async willSendRequest(request) {
    // some logic
  }

  async getCompanies() {
    return this.get(`some_api_url`);
  }

  async getCompanyByName(name) {
    return this.get(`some_api_url?companyName=name`);
  }
  //other external API endpoints
...
}
```

`main.ts`

```
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs: schema,
    schema,
    resolvers,
    dataSources,
    cache: 'bounded',
  });
  await server.start();
```

Edit: I'm limiting the number of unique datasource API calls because the API I'm hitting has a limit. I tried instantiating a counter in the `RESTDataSource` class and using it in the `willSendRequest` to count how many datasource calls there are, but the problem is this is counting request by request and has no access to all the API requests that are coming from the resolver. For instance, if the `getCompanies` API can be called only once and I have 2 upcoming requests, I'll have to let one of them pass and only stop the second, because at that point I don't know there's a second request coming. My team has agreed to stop both requests in case the number of upcoming requests exceeds the available limit for the endpoint (this is specified in our database), so this is why I need to know beforehand how many API requests are there before even allowing the first request.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to preflight a query to check how many times each resolver might be called. You have the further problem of multiple users making requests at the same time which will require throttling across sessions. Are you caching your API calls to minimize requests to the throttled APIs?

Comment: Yes I am. The API endpoints called in the datasource have a certain limit, this is why I am trying to count how many requests there are for each datasource. Thank you, I'm not finding a way to get all the API requests prior to sending the first request so I think I'll go with initializing a counter in the `RESTDataSource` as a class property and increment it each time a request is made in the `willSendRequest`. It won't give me the exact behavior I'm looking for but at least I've got a counter and can reject the requests when the threshold is exceeded.